# Flashing BIOS on Acer Aspire S7: wrong ROM file size?

Tags: laptop, boot, bios, acer-aspire

I'm trying to update the BIOS on my Acer Aspire S7, which is only running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (no Windows), so that its fan would stop being so noisy. I followed the instructions on [this person's post](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/53158-InsydeFlash-for-DOS-(Acer-Aspire-S7-391)).

Specifically, it is an S7 391 and I was attempting to download BIOS version [2.18](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/BIOS/BIOS/BIOS_Acer_2.18_A_A.zip?acerid=635277828259424282&Step1=ULTRA-THIN&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%20S7-391&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_6) which was described as "Improve thermal performance."

I ended up having the exact same problem:

```
C:\> FLASHIT.EXE ISFLASH.FD

Insyde Flash Utility for InsydeH2O
Error: This ROM file size isn’t correct.
Error: ROM size: 4728c0 Current BIOS size: 100000
```

I read somewhere that this was often caused by an incorrect BIOS, but I know for fact I have downloaded the right one. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: The `ISFLASH.FD` file appears to be an EFI executable, and can't be flashed directly like that. The expected size is `0x100000` bytes (1 MiB), while the file you got has `0x4728c0` bytes (~4.45 MiB).

Comment: Is there a file that can be flashed directly in there?

Comment: It doesn't seem so.